# Writing list of dictionaries to a csv file but getting ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I've found the answer. Instead of writerow I needed writerows.

So the correct code goes like this:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    import csv


    def process_cdr():
        f = open(files)
        for lines in f:
            if 'ERS.VA' == lines[39:45]:
                d = {   'mnc'    : lines[13:15],
                        'tac-lb' : lines[52:54],
                'tac-hb' : lines[61:63],
                'TAC' : lines[61:63]+lines[52:54],
                'TAC_DEC' : str(int(lines[61:63]+lines[52:54],16))       
            }

                if '02' in d['mnc']:
                    mnc02.append(d)
                elif '03' in d['mnc']:
                    mnc03.append(d)
                elif '04' in d['mnc']:
                    mnc04.append(d)
                else:
                    pass
            else:
                pass


    mnc02 =[]
    mnc03 =[]
    mnc04 =[]

    files = 'teste.txt'

    process_cdr()

    mnc_02_path = 'tac_mnc02.csv'
    keys_mnc02 = mnc02[0].keys()
    with open(mnc_02_path,'wb') as resultado: 
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(resultado, keys_mnc02)
        dict_writer.writeheader()
        dict_writer.writerows(mnc02)

    mnc_03_path = 'tac_mnc03.txt'
    keys_mnc03 = mnc03[0].keys()
    with open(mnc_03_path,'wb') as resultado: 
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(resultado, keys_mnc03)
        dict_writer.writeheader()
        dict_writer.writerows(mnc03)

    mnc_04_path = 'tac_mnc04.txt'
    keys_mnc04 = mnc04[0].keys()
    with open(mnc_04_path,'wb') as resultado: 
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(resultado, keys_mnc04)
        dict_writer.writeheader()
        dict_writer.writerows(mnc04)
```

Thanks everyone, specially lapinkoira.
I've searched here a lot but I still can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    import csv


    def process_cdr():
        f = open(files)
        for lines in f:
            if 'ERS.VA' == lines[39:45]:
                d = {   'mnc'    : lines[13:15],
                        'tac-lb' : lines[52:54],
                'tac-hb' : lines[61:63],
                'TAC' : lines[61:63]+lines[52:54],
                'TAC_DEC' : str(int(lines[61:63]+lines[52:54],16))       
            }

                if '02' in d['mnc']:
                    mnc02.append(d)
                elif '03' in d['mnc']:
                    mnc03.append(d)
                elif '04' in d['mnc']:
                    mnc04.append(d)
                else:
                    pass
            else:
                pass


    mnc02 =[]
    mnc03 =[]
    mnc04 =[]

    files = 'teste.txt'

    process_cdr()

    mnc_02_path = 'tac_mnc02.csv'
    keys_mnc02 = mnc02[0].keys()
    with open(mnc_02_path,'wb') as resultado: 
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(resultado, keys_mnc02)
        dict_writer.writeheader()
        dict_writer.writerow(mnc02)

    mnc_03_path = 'tac_mnc03.txt'
    keys_mnc03 = mnc03[0].keys()
    with open(mnc_03_path,'wb') as resultado: 
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(resultado, keys_mnc03)
        dict_writer.writeheader()
        dict_writer.writerow(mnc03)

    mnc_04_path = 'tac_mnc04.txt'
    keys_mnc04 = mnc04[0].keys()
    with open(mnc_04_path,'wb') as resultado: 
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(resultado, keys_mnc04)
        dict_writer.writeheader()
        dict_writer.writerow(mnc04)
```

When I print the fieldnames,e.g. keys_mnc02, I get: ['tac-lb', 'TAC_DEC', 'mnc', 'tac-hb', 'TAC']

And the error begins with:

ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: {'tac-lb': '7e', 'TAC_DEC': '33150', 'mnc': '02', 'tac-hb': '81', 'TAC': '817e'}, {'tac-lb': '7e', 'TAC_DEC': '33150', 'mnc': '02', 'tac-hb': '81', 'TAC': '817e'}, {'tac-lb': 'EE', 'TAC_DEC': '32750', 'mnc': '02', 'tac-hb': '7F', 'TAC': '7FEE'}, {'tac-lb': 'FC', 'TAC_DEC': '32252', 'mnc': '02', 'tac-hb': '7D', 'TAC': '7DFC'}, {'tac-lb': 'C3', 'TAC_DEC': '32451', 'mnc': '02', 'tac-hb': '7E', 'TAC': '7EC3'}, {'tac-lb': 'B4', 'TAC_DEC': '32180', 'mnc': '02', 'tac-hb': '7D', 'TAC': '7DB4'}, {'tac-lb': 'B9', 'TAC_DEC': '32185', 'mnc': '02', 'tac-hb': '7D', 'TAC': '7DB9'}, {'tac-lb': '4F', 'TAC_DEC': '33103', 'mnc': '02', 'tac-hb': '81', 'TAC': '814F'}, {'tac-lb': '4D', 'TAC_DEC': '33101', 'mnc': '02', 'tac-hb': '81', 'TAC': '814D'}, {'tac-lb': '4E', 'TAC_DEC': '33102', 'mnc': '02', 'tac-hb': '81', 'TAC': '814E'}, {'tac-lb': '50', 'TAC_DEC': '33104', 'mnc': '02', 'tac-hb': '81', 'TAC': '8150'}, {'tac-lb': '51', 'TAC_DEC': '33105', 'mnc': '02', 'tac-hb': '81', 'TAC': '8151'}, {'tac-lb': '52', 'TAC_DEC': '33106', 'mnc': '02', 'tac-hb': '81', 'TAC': '8152'}, {'tac-lb': '7E', 'TAC_DEC': '39550', 'mnc': '02', 'tac-hb': '9A', 'TAC': '9A7E'}, {'tac-lb': '65', 'TAC_DEC': '38501', 'mnc': '02', 'tac-hb': '96', 'TAC': '9665'}, {'tac-lb': '66', 'TAC_DEC': '38502', 'mnc': '02', 'tac-hb': '96', 'TAC': '9666'}, {'tac-lb': '67', 'TAC_DEC': '38503', 'mnc': '02', 'tac-hb': '96', 'TAC': '9667'}, {'tac-lb': '68', 'TAC_DEC': '38504', 'mnc': '02', 'tac-hb': '96', 'TAC': '9668'}, {'tac-lb': '69', 'TAC_DEC': '38505', 'mnc': '02', 'tac-hb': '96', 'TAC': '9669'}, {'tac-lb': '6A', 'TAC_DEC': '38506', 'mnc': '02', 'tac-hb': '96', 'TAC': '966A'}, {'tac-lb': '6B', 'TAC_DEC': '38507', 'mnc': '02', 'tac-hb': '96', 'TAC': '966B'}, {'tac-lb': '6C', 'TAC_DEC': '38508', 'mnc': '02', 'tac-hb': '96', 'TAC': '966C'}, {'tac-lb': '6D', 'TAC_DEC': '38509', 'mnc': '02', 'tac-hb': '96', 'TAC': '966D'}, {'tac-lb': 'B1', 'TAC_DEC': '33201', 'mnc': '02', 'tac-hb': '81', 'TAC': '81B1'}, {'tac-lb': 'B2', 'TAC_DEC': '33202', 'mnc': '02', 'tac-hb': '81', 'TAC': '81B2'},

etc etc ..

Can anyone help me?

Thank you!

Comment: In which line is the ValueError happening?

Comment: Just a side comment: you don't need any of the `else: pass` statement. Having an `else` that does nothing is the same as having no `else` to begin with.

Comment: @lapinkoira line 48.. I just updated it xD

Answer (score 0):

With the values you provided this is working for me:

```
In [23]: keys_mnc03
Out[23]: ['tac-lb', 'TAC_DEC', 'mnc', 'tac-hb', 'TAC']

mnc03 = huge list of dictionaries

with open("test.txt",'wb') as resultado:
     dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(resultado, keys_mnc03)
     dict_writer.writeheader()
     for d in mnc03:
         dict_writer.writerow(d)
```

You can also use this code to check if the fields are in the list:

```
for e in mnc03:
    for key in e.keys():
        if key not in keys_mnc03:
            print "key %s not in keys" % key
```

Comment: So, I did this filtering by printing the value in keys_mnc03 as a result I got? ['tac-lb', 'TAC_DEC', 'mnc', 'tac-hb', 'TAC'], and if you notice every dict inside my list has exactly those heads? {'tac-lb': '7e', 'TAC_DEC': '33150', 'mnc': '02', 'tac-hb': '81', 'TAC': '817e'}

Comment: I had to make it a answer cause there are too much values

Comment: I found the problem @lapinkoira!! I can't believe it... but I had only to change writerow to writerows... thank you very much for you help and time!

Comment: Yeah it's weird in the mnc02's case it was working... for me to make it works I had to loop the mnc03 and insert each row or as you said you can use the writerows also, I am not so friendly with csv's library methods

Answer (score 0):

@lapinkoira

The value of mnc03 is:

[{'tac-lb': 'A9', 'TAC_DEC': '31401', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '7A', 'TAC': '7AA9'}, {'tac-lb': 'A9', 'TAC_DEC': '31401', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '7A', 'TAC': '7AA9'}, {'tac-lb': '7F', 'TAC_DEC': '31103', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '797F'}, {'tac-lb': '7F', 'TAC_DEC': '31103', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '797F'}, {'tac-lb': '87', 'TAC_DEC': '31111', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7987'}, {'tac-lb': '87', 'TAC_DEC': '31111', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7987'}, {'tac-lb': '8A', 'TAC_DEC': '31114', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '798A'}, {'tac-lb': '8A', 'TAC_DEC': '31114', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '798A'}, {'tac-lb': '8B', 'TAC_DEC': '31115', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '798B'}, {'tac-lb': '8B', 'TAC_DEC': '31115', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '798B'}, {'tac-lb': 'AB', 'TAC_DEC': '31147', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79AB'}, {'tac-lb': 'AB', 'TAC_DEC': '31147', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79AB'}, {'tac-lb': 'AC', 'TAC_DEC': '31148', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79AC'}, {'tac-lb': 'AC', 'TAC_DEC': '31148', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79AC'}, {'tac-lb': 'AD', 'TAC_DEC': '31149', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79AD'}, {'tac-lb': 'AD', 'TAC_DEC': '31149', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79AD'}, {'tac-lb': 'B8', 'TAC_DEC': '31160', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79B8'}, {'tac-lb': 'B8', 'TAC_DEC': '31160', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79B8'}, {'tac-lb': 'BD', 'TAC_DEC': '31165', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79BD'}, {'tac-lb': 'BD', 'TAC_DEC': '31165', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79BD'}, {'tac-lb': 'BE', 'TAC_DEC': '31166', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79BE'}, {'tac-lb': 'BE', 'TAC_DEC': '31166', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79BE'}, {'tac-lb': 'BF', 'TAC_DEC': '31167', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79BF'}, {'tac-lb': 'BF', 'TAC_DEC': '31167', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79BF'}, {'tac-lb': 'C0', 'TAC_DEC': '31168', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79C0'}, {'tac-lb': 'C0', 'TAC_DEC': '31168', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79C0'}, {'tac-lb': 'C1', 'TAC_DEC': '31169', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79C1'}, {'tac-lb': 'C1', 'TAC_DEC': '31169', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79C1'}, {'tac-lb': 'C3', 'TAC_DEC': '31171', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79C3'}, {'tac-lb': 'C3', 'TAC_DEC': '31171', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79C3'}, {'tac-lb': 'C4', 'TAC_DEC': '31172', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79C4'}, {'tac-lb': 'C4', 'TAC_DEC': '31172', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79C4'}, {'tac-lb': 'C5', 'TAC_DEC': '31173', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79C5'}, {'tac-lb': 'C5', 'TAC_DEC': '31173', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79C5'}, {'tac-lb': 'C8', 'TAC_DEC': '31176', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79C8'}, {'tac-lb': 'C8', 'TAC_DEC': '31176', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79C8'}, {'tac-lb': '86', 'TAC_DEC': '31110', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7986'}, {'tac-lb': '86', 'TAC_DEC': '31110', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7986'}, {'tac-lb': '89', 'TAC_DEC': '31113', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7989'}, {'tac-lb': '89', 'TAC_DEC': '31113', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7989'}, {'tac-lb': '94', 'TAC_DEC': '31124', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7994'}, {'tac-lb': '94', 'TAC_DEC': '31124', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7994'}, {'tac-lb': '9C', 'TAC_DEC': '31132', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '799C'}, {'tac-lb': '9C', 'TAC_DEC': '31132', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '799C'}, {'tac-lb': '9D', 'TAC_DEC': '31133', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '799D'}, {'tac-lb': '9D', 'TAC_DEC': '31133', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '799D'}, {'tac-lb': '9E', 'TAC_DEC': '31134', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '799E'}, {'tac-lb': '9E', 'TAC_DEC': '31134', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '799E'}, {'tac-lb': '9F', 'TAC_DEC': '31135', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '799F'}, {'tac-lb': '9F', 'TAC_DEC': '31135', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '799F'}, {'tac-lb': 'A0', 'TAC_DEC': '31136', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79A0'}, {'tac-lb': 'A0', 'TAC_DEC': '31136', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79A0'}, {'tac-lb': 'A5', 'TAC_DEC': '31141', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79A5'}, {'tac-lb': 'A5', 'TAC_DEC': '31141', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79A5'}, {'tac-lb': 'B9', 'TAC_DEC': '31161', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79B9'}, {'tac-lb': 'B9', 'TAC_DEC': '31161', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79B9'}, {'tac-lb': 'BA', 'TAC_DEC': '31162', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79BA'}, {'tac-lb': 'BA', 'TAC_DEC': '31162', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79BA'}, {'tac-lb': 'BB', 'TAC_DEC': '31163', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79BB'}, {'tac-lb': 'BB', 'TAC_DEC': '31163', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79BB'}, {'tac-lb': 'BC', 'TAC_DEC': '31164', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79BC'}, {'tac-lb': 'BC', 'TAC_DEC': '31164', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79BC'}, {'tac-lb': 'C7', 'TAC_DEC': '31175', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79C7'}, {'tac-lb': 'C7', 'TAC_DEC': '31175', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79C7'}, {'tac-lb': 'CB', 'TAC_DEC': '31179', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79CB'}, {'tac-lb': 'CB', 'TAC_DEC': '31179', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79CB'}, {'tac-lb': '0D', 'TAC_DEC': '31501', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '7B', 'TAC': '7B0D'}, {'tac-lb': '0D', 'TAC_DEC': '31501', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '7B', 'TAC': '7B0D'}, {'tac-lb': '8F', 'TAC_DEC': '31119', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '798F'}, {'tac-lb': '8F', 'TAC_DEC': '31119', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '798F'}, {'tac-lb': '92', 'TAC_DEC': '31122', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7992'}, {'tac-lb': '92', 'TAC_DEC': '31122', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7992'}, {'tac-lb': 'A1', 'TAC_DEC': '31137', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79A1'}, {'tac-lb': 'A1', 'TAC_DEC': '31137', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79A1'}, {'tac-lb': 'A2', 'TAC_DEC': '31138', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79A2'}, {'tac-lb': 'A2', 'TAC_DEC': '31138', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79A2'}, {'tac-lb': 'A3', 'TAC_DEC': '31139', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79A3'}, {'tac-lb': 'A3', 'TAC_DEC': '31139', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79A3'}, {'tac-lb': 'A4', 'TAC_DEC': '31140', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79A4'}, {'tac-lb': 'A4', 'TAC_DEC': '31140', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79A4'}, {'tac-lb': 'A6', 'TAC_DEC': '31142', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79A6'}, {'tac-lb': 'A6', 'TAC_DEC': '31142', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79A6'}, {'tac-lb': 'A7', 'TAC_DEC': '31143', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79A7'}, {'tac-lb': 'A7', 'TAC_DEC': '31143', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79A7'}, {'tac-lb': 'A8', 'TAC_DEC': '31144', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79A8'}, {'tac-lb': 'A8', 'TAC_DEC': '31144', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79A8'}, {'tac-lb': 'B5', 'TAC_DEC': '31157', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79B5'}, {'tac-lb': 'B5', 'TAC_DEC': '31157', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79B5'}, {'tac-lb': 'B6', 'TAC_DEC': '31158', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79B6'}, {'tac-lb': 'B6', 'TAC_DEC': '31158', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79B6'}, {'tac-lb': 'B7', 'TAC_DEC': '31159', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79B7'}, {'tac-lb': 'B7', 'TAC_DEC': '31159', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79B7'}, {'tac-lb': 'C2', 'TAC_DEC': '31170', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79C2'}, {'tac-lb': 'C2', 'TAC_DEC': '31170', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79C2'}, {'tac-lb': 'CC', 'TAC_DEC': '31180', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79CC'}, {'tac-lb': 'CC', 'TAC_DEC': '31180', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79CC'}, {'tac-lb': 'DE', 'TAC_DEC': '31198', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79DE'}, {'tac-lb': 'DE', 'TAC_DEC': '31198', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79DE'}, {'tac-lb': '9D', 'TAC_DEC': '31901', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '7C', 'TAC': '7C9D'}, {'tac-lb': '9D', 'TAC_DEC': '31901', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '7C', 'TAC': '7C9D'}, {'tac-lb': '9E', 'TAC_DEC': '31902', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '7C', 'TAC': '7C9E'}, {'tac-lb': '9E', 'TAC_DEC': '31902', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '7C', 'TAC': '7C9E'}, {'tac-lb': 'AF', 'TAC_DEC': '31151', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79AF'}, {'tac-lb': 'AF', 'TAC_DEC': '31151', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79AF'}, {'tac-lb': 'B1', 'TAC_DEC': '31153', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79B1'}, {'tac-lb': 'B1', 'TAC_DEC': '31153', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79B1'}, {'tac-lb': 'B2', 'TAC_DEC': '31154', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79B2'}, {'tac-lb': 'B2', 'TAC_DEC': '31154', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79B2'}, {'tac-lb': 'B3', 'TAC_DEC': '31155', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79B3'}, {'tac-lb': 'B3', 'TAC_DEC': '31155', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79B3'}, {'tac-lb': 'B4', 'TAC_DEC': '31156', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79B4'}, {'tac-lb': 'B4', 'TAC_DEC': '31156', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79B4'}, {'tac-lb': 'A9', 'TAC_DEC': '31145', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79A9'}, {'tac-lb': 'A9', 'TAC_DEC': '31145', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79A9'}, {'tac-lb': 'AA', 'TAC_DEC': '31146', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79AA'}, {'tac-lb': 'AA', 'TAC_DEC': '31146', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79AA'}, {'tac-lb': 'AE', 'TAC_DEC': '31150', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79AE'}, {'tac-lb': 'AE', 'TAC_DEC': '31150', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79AE'}, {'tac-lb': 'C9', 'TAC_DEC': '31177', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79C9'}, {'tac-lb': 'C9', 'TAC_DEC': '31177', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79C9'}, {'tac-lb': 'CA', 'TAC_DEC': '31178', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79CA'}, {'tac-lb': 'CA', 'TAC_DEC': '31178', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79CA'}, {'tac-lb': 'C6', 'TAC_DEC': '31174', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79C6'}, {'tac-lb': 'C6', 'TAC_DEC': '31174', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79C6'}, {'tac-lb': 'B0', 'TAC_DEC': '31152', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79B0'}, {'tac-lb': 'B0', 'TAC_DEC': '31152', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79B0'}, {'tac-lb': '99', 'TAC_DEC': '39321', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '99', 'TAC': '9999'}, {'tac-lb': '99', 'TAC_DEC': '39321', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '99', 'TAC': '9999'}, {'tac-lb': '7D', 'TAC_DEC': '31101', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '797D'}, {'tac-lb': '7D', 'TAC_DEC': '31101', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '797D'}, {'tac-lb': '7E', 'TAC_DEC': '31102', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '797E'}, {'tac-lb': '7E', 'TAC_DEC': '31102', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '797E'}, {'tac-lb': '80', 'TAC_DEC': '31104', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7980'}, {'tac-lb': '80', 'TAC_DEC': '31104', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7980'}, {'tac-lb': '81', 'TAC_DEC': '31105', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7981'}, {'tac-lb': '81', 'TAC_DEC': '31105', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7981'}, {'tac-lb': '82', 'TAC_DEC': '31106', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7982'}, {'tac-lb': '82', 'TAC_DEC': '31106', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7982'}, {'tac-lb': '83', 'TAC_DEC': '31107', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7983'}, {'tac-lb': '83', 'TAC_DEC': '31107', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7983'}, {'tac-lb': '84', 'TAC_DEC': '31108', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7984'}, {'tac-lb': '84', 'TAC_DEC': '31108', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7984'}, {'tac-lb': '85', 'TAC_DEC': '31109', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7985'}, {'tac-lb': '85', 'TAC_DEC': '31109', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7985'}, {'tac-lb': '88', 'TAC_DEC': '31112', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7988'}, {'tac-lb': '88', 'TAC_DEC': '31112', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7988'}, {'tac-lb': '8C', 'TAC_DEC': '31116', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '798C'}, {'tac-lb': '8C', 'TAC_DEC': '31116', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '798C'}, {'tac-lb': '8D', 'TAC_DEC': '31117', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '798D'}, {'tac-lb': '8D', 'TAC_DEC': '31117', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '798D'}, {'tac-lb': '8E', 'TAC_DEC': '31118', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '798E'}, {'tac-lb': '8E', 'TAC_DEC': '31118', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '798E'}, {'tac-lb': '90', 'TAC_DEC': '31120', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7990'}, {'tac-lb': '90', 'TAC_DEC': '31120', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7990'}, {'tac-lb': '91', 'TAC_DEC': '31121', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7991'}, {'tac-lb': '91', 'TAC_DEC': '31121', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7991'}, {'tac-lb': '93', 'TAC_DEC': '31123', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7993'}, {'tac-lb': '93', 'TAC_DEC': '31123', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7993'}, {'tac-lb': '95', 'TAC_DEC': '31125', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7995'}, {'tac-lb': '95', 'TAC_DEC': '31125', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7995'}, {'tac-lb': '96', 'TAC_DEC': '31126', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7996'}, {'tac-lb': '96', 'TAC_DEC': '31126', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7996'}, {'tac-lb': '97', 'TAC_DEC': '31127', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7997'}, {'tac-lb': '97', 'TAC_DEC': '31127', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7997'}, {'tac-lb': '98', 'TAC_DEC': '31128', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7998'}, {'tac-lb': '98', 'TAC_DEC': '31128', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7998'}, {'tac-lb': '99', 'TAC_DEC': '31129', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7999'}, {'tac-lb': '99', 'TAC_DEC': '31129', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '7999'}, {'tac-lb': '9A', 'TAC_DEC': '31130', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '799A'}, {'tac-lb': '9A', 'TAC_DEC': '31130', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '799A'}, {'tac-lb': '9B', 'TAC_DEC': '31131', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '799B'}, {'tac-lb': '9B', 'TAC_DEC': '31131', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '799B'}, {'tac-lb': 'A2', 'TAC_DEC': '31650', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '7B', 'TAC': '7BA2'}, {'tac-lb': 'A2', 'TAC_DEC': '31650', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '7B', 'TAC': '7BA2'}, {'tac-lb': '12', 'TAC_DEC': '31250', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '7A', 'TAC': '7A12'}, {'tac-lb': '12', 'TAC_DEC': '31250', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '7A', 'TAC': '7A12'}, {'tac-lb': '13', 'TAC_DEC': '31251', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '7A', 'TAC': '7A13'}, {'tac-lb': '13', 'TAC_DEC': '31251', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '7A', 'TAC': '7A13'}, {'tac-lb': 'CF', 'TAC_DEC': '31183', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79CF'}, {'tac-lb': 'CF', 'TAC_DEC': '31183', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79CF'}, {'tac-lb': 'CD', 'TAC_DEC': '31181', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79CD'}, {'tac-lb': 'CD', 'TAC_DEC': '31181', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79CD'}, {'tac-lb': 'CD', 'TAC_DEC': '31181', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79CD'}, {'tac-lb': 'CE', 'TAC_DEC': '31182', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79CE'}, {'tac-lb': 'CE', 'TAC_DEC': '31182', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79CE'}, {'tac-lb': 'CE', 'TAC_DEC': '31182', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79CE'}, {'tac-lb': 'CD', 'TAC_DEC': '31181', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79CD'}, {'tac-lb': 'CE', 'TAC_DEC': '31182', 'mnc': '03', 'tac-hb': '79', 'TAC': '79CE'}]